# Similar to C#'s Process.Close event in Java?

Tags: java, c#, swing, events, process

If I start a process using ProcessBuilder in Java, is there a way to listen if that process has been closed? What I would like to do is Start a process, insert a record to a mySQL table, and when the process is killed or the user is exited, then execute a delete statement in that mysql table. I've already done it in C#, but my users requested the application to be able to run on linux and mac too, and I stuck at this part.

Comment: Uhm, why go through an external process at all for this? There is JDBC, there is JooQ.

Comment: Probably you misunderstood me. I'm creating a launcher for a game and inserting the user's name into the DB, to make sure he's using the launcher provided by the server. When he logs in, and starts the game, before the process is started, the application inserts it's username into the DB (using JDBC) and then if he enters the game, a server-side application checks if the username is in the table. If yes, then he's using it. I need to make sure that his name is removed from the table if he's closing the game, that's why I need the listener for the process close event, if it exists.

Comment: You can try this - http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/java.util/from-runtime.exec-to-processbuilder.html, it says, read process inputstream , when that comes to null, means process is complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this my friend.

```
public class YourClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        ProcessBuilder  yourProcess = new ProcessBuilder(); 
        Process process = yourProcess.start();//Creates a new object containing your process
        //Your insert SQL stuff...
        try {
            process.waitFor();//Waits until the process finish
            //Your delete SQL stuff...
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            System.out.println("The process finished unexpectly");;
        }            
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't it makes my main thread unresponsive? Ah, I guess I should just put that into another thread and that should solve it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use one of the Android lifecycles which is the onDestroy() method just be sure you'll call the finish() on one of your events.

In addition you can also put the finish() on an Alert Dialog button which popups when user press the backbutton on the login screen. You'll probably add the method onBackPressed() then your final code should look something like this:

```
 onDestroy(){
 super.onDestroy();
 //place your delete function here..
 }

 //then call this when user pressed home button or backbutton on login screen
 finish();

 //or
 onBackPressed(){
 //Show a dialog
 //then put the finish() function on the positive button of a dialog.
 dialog.setPositiveButton...{
 finish();
 }
```

just be sure you are using the finish() function when you have a onDestroy() method because it will server as a trigger for it or it could be if the users phone exceeds its memory capacity and the app is forced to end.

Comment: The question doesn't appear to be about Android.